# Mongoid embedded document belongs_to embedded document

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I have few models:

```
class Product
...
embeds_many :items
...
end

class Item
...
embedded_in :product
...
end

class Cart
...
embeds_many :line_items
...
end

class LineItem
...
embedded_in :cart
belongs_to :product
belongs_to :item
...
end
```

line_item.item belongs to Item embedded in Product

Why item from LineItem is always nil?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this is wrong structure... the embedded documents cannot be referenced in any other model than the parent documents.

as the documentation says

> ### Embedded 1-n:
>
> One to many relationships where the children are **embedded in** the parent document.
>
> ### Referneced 1-n:
>
> One to many relationships where the children are **stored in a separate collection** from the parent document

so there is no way that an embedded doc ( stored as an attribute in some document ) to be referenced as a separate collection ( like the **Referenced 1-n** relations)..

you can look into altering the models definitions to suite your purposes...
take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17935525/embeded-document-with-belong-to-association-in-mongoid) which discuss the same problem