# Mongoid: How Can I Reference a Document from within an Embedded Document

Tags: mongoid

```
class Customer
  embeds_many :addresses
  #....
end

class Address
  embedded_in :customer
  belongs_to :region
  #...
end
```

I don't care about ever finding all the embedded addresses that reference a region, but I want to be able to use the region= and region_id accessors that would be generated by belongs_to.

The documentation says both sides of the relationship must be defined UNLESS one of them is embedded, but when I leave out the Region-side association, I get:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
    from /[...]/accessors.rb:113:in `needs_no_database_query?'
```

Comment: only to create field with `region_id`. It's impossible to make references in embedded objects.

Answer (score 0):

this is wrong structure... the embedded documents cannot be referenced in any other model than the parent documents.

as the documentation says

> ### Embedded 1-n:
>
> One to many relationships where the children are **embedded in** the parent document.
>
> ### Referneced 1-n:
>
> One to many relationships where the children are **stored in a separate collection** from the parent document

so there is no way that an embedded doc ( stored as an attribute in some document ) to be referenced as a separate collection ( like the **Referenced 1-n** relations)..

you can look into altering the models definitions to suite your purposes...
take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17935525/embeded-document-with-belong-to-association-in-mongoid) which discuss the same problem